# Receiving error "0x1" in Windows Task Schedule

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have successfully run a task in Windows Task Scheduler for an R file. I needed to run a total of four files, and the first one ran successfully while the other three did not. I got the error "0x1" for the three that did not run. I'm using a .bat file and only changed the name of the file that is running for each task. Is there a reason that one task would work but the three that are exactly like it would not?

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue last night will all of my scheduled headless tests.

They are Run whether user is logged on or not and Do Not Store Password. I have not used Run with highest privileges.

The actions are full path without using Run In.

Not sure why they would massively fail when they've been running (some of them) for 2 1/2 years.